# Is there a male counterpart to being a virgin?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, slang, gender-positive

Is there a word for a sexually-inexperienced man/boy - like how ***virgin*** is for a woman/girl?

I'm from Norway, and here the word ***svenn*** is used for males who have yet to sleep with someone.  Although ***jomfru*** (virgin) is also more and more used on males.

***Svenn*** is also used for a person who's been studying (often a craft) under a master, and will soon become a master himself.  I guess ***apprentice*** would be a good translation, although a ***svenn*** may himself have younger boys beneath him, whom he instructs in the craft.

***Svenn*** is also used in ***peppersvenn*** (an unmarried man 30 years old or older), as opposed to ***peppermø*** (***mø*** = maid)(an unmarried woman 30 years old or older).

So is there a "male" version of ***virgin*** - and perhaps a male-specific word for **losing *his* virginity**?

Comment: I posted this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290692/when-did-men-start-to-lose-their-virginity) today and it might be interesting to you. :)

Comment: Just for your information, you want to use "losing" and not "loosing" here.

Comment: Ironically, I believe the word *svenn* is cognate to the English word *swain*, which means [a man who is a woman's lover](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swain).

Comment: Do you have a source for "svenn" being used for male virgins in Norwegian? The only meanings I've encountered for it before is for it either it being a young man, or a craftsman's apprentice. Googling doesn't turn up anything resembling your definition, and neither does Wikipedia, Store Norske, or www.nob-ordbok.uio.no/

Comment: It's gender-neutral, as in [The 40-Year-Old Virgin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405422/)

Comment: at the age of 30 Virgin becomes Wizard for men and for women I assume it's Sorceress

Comment: [John Locke's attempt to cure Isaac Newton of his virginity failed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton#Personal_relations). "His note to the latter included the charge that Locke "endeavoured to embroil me with woemen"."

Comment: You can also simply google things like "he's a virgin" and "lose his virginity" to see that it's used plenty.

Comment: If you want to avoid the female connotation of the word `virgin`, you can use the term `virginal`. *The man is virginal.*

Comment: @Rathony I know :-D !  I decided to ask in the morning... when i logged-on in the evening, the first question I saw was yours.  After reading it, I decided mine was different enough.

Comment: @eirikdaude I guess the best example is the use of "pepper*svenn*" as the male equivalent of "pepper*mø*"...  It *is* a rather obscure usage of the word (and getting more so).

Comment: @eirikdaude To add to Baard's reply;  See the entry [peppersvenn](http://www.nob-ordbok.uio.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?OPP=peppersvenn) at Språkrådet, which says "old bachelor".

Comment: @PålGD That doesn't support "svenn" being synonymous with "virgin" as originally claimed though? According with the definition from [etymologisk ordbok](http://issuu.com/kaggeforlag/docs/01_norsk_etymologisk_ordbok_leseutd/32) it merely means "gammel ungkar" (old bachelor), which (mostly) correlates with [the definition for "svenn" from Språlrådet.](http://www.nob-ordbok.uio.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?OPP=svenn&ant_bokmaal=5&ant_nynorsk=5&begge=+&ordbok=begge)

Comment: It should be noted that, were it not for the *Virgin Mary* as depicted in Christian religion, "virgin" would likely be considered to be a mild obscenity.

Comment: Somewhat tangential FYI, but it sounds like *svenn* might be a better match to [*journeyman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journeyman) than *apprentice*, based on the description.

Comment: @HotLicks: Really? The word has other common, positive uses (virgin snow; extra virgin olive oil). It is in no way an obscenity...

Comment: @psmears: Well, those uses *are* predated by the Virgin Mary, so we cannot really tell, can we? ;-)

Comment: @psmears - You're assuming that those uses would have survived 2000 years without the Church to secure the meaning?

Answer (score 78):

*[Virgin](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/virgin_1)* is used to refer to a person who has never had sex or a person who has no experience in a particular activity. This person can be male or female.

Comment: This is what allows Jeff Dunham to make the joke with Achmed, asking ["did they say it would be only female virgins?"](https://youtu.be/XMpvvnOHC1U?t=5m3s)

Comment: I've occasionally heard the term to mean having had receptive sex rather than just any form of it in certain contexts. `K: "I'm not a virgin!" C: "You mean you've lost your virginity or you've taken someone else's? You don't look like the pitchin' kind to me."`

Comment: @zxq9 - that quote seems to demonstrate that _virgin_ can mean either way, other wise `C` wouldn't need to clarify. `K` has either lost his virginity through some prior sexual relations, or he has taken someone else's, but whether he was giving or receiving, he's no longer a virgin. `K` seems to make a distinction between losing one's own virginity and taking someone else's.

Comment: In the movie, "The 40-Year-Old Virgin", the protagonist is not a woman.

Comment: @Johnny Another school of thought considers the giving virginity and the receiving virginity to be separate.

Comment: @Cronax How do you not lose both when you lose one?

Comment: @Cronax - How does one give or receive virginity? One is a virgin by default until the criteria for not being one are met.

Comment: @JimboJonny That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying there's a difference between being the receiving party and the giving party. Different sexual acts deal with different virginities. In the case of a man, performing penetration in this case would be different from receiving it.

Comment: Virgin snow has no gender.  It refers to snow that is untouched.  That you think virginity is about sex just shows how much you think about sex.  You pervs : )

Comment: @Cronax - better late than never on the reply...anyway: That's not receiving virginity. That's losing virginity by the sexual act known colloquially as "receiving". Nobody received the virginity. The virginity was "taken", perhaps, gone forever. But even that is a specific colloquialism (you can't just substitute other tangentially related words), and has nothing to do with who's penetrating (a woman still "takes" a man's virginity if he is a virgin when they have intercourse).

Comment: @JimboJonny You're referring to how one 'loses' their virginity. I'm referring to the virginity itself, which some people hold to have two 'types', as I described. We can debate the original intent of the term virginity all day but if enough people use a word a certain way, it is no longer 'incorrect'.

Comment: @Cronax - You've given no evidence that anyone uses the word that way except for you. Do you have any source for the claim that there is a new common usage for the word where someone is considered to "receive" the "virginity itself" from a sexual act?

Comment: @JimboJonny If you're not going to bother reading what I'm saying then I'm not sure I have a way of explaining it to you. Nobody is 'receiving' the virginity itself.

Answer (score 20):

In English the word "virgin" has absolutely zero gender requirements. Virgins are virgins, male or female.

It simply means anyone that has not had sexual intercourse. It is quite normal to refer to a male having lost his virginity, or referring to a male virgin, etc.

Comment: It might also be good to mention that this is a modern phenomenon. 'Virgin' meant 'a woman who has not given birth' or simply 'a young woman' in the past.

Comment: @otakucode: When? The 13th centrury barely counts, while *maiden* is a rather different word

Answer (score 10):

A slang term exclusively used for males is  ***cherry-boy*** (*cherry boy*). *[Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cherry%20boy)* has many entries for the term also.

*Cassell's Dictionary of Slang* has the slang term ***cherry prick*** also but I've never heard it before.

The terms above are uncommon unlike *virgin* which is used for both males and females.

---

Here are the definitions from *[Cassell's Dictionary of Slang](https://books.google.es/books/about/Cassell_s_Dictionary_of_Slang.html?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&redir_esc=y)* (by Jonathon Green):

[image]

Transcription:

> **cherry-boy** *n.* [1970s+] (*US*) a male virgin [CHERRY adj. (1)] 
> **cherry prick** *n.* [20C+] a male virgin. [CHERRY adj. (1) + PRICK n. (2)]

They are related to the term *cherry* meaning a female virgin (from 1920s).

---

Here is an excerpt about *cherry boy* and its origin in military slang during World War II in Japan:

> **Cherry boy**⁠—*Cheri boi*(Chay-ree boy). 
>  So many of the young American GIs who took part in the military Occupation of Japan had had no sexual experience that the term "cherry boy" was one of the first "new words” the GIs learned. Japanese prostitutes delighted at breaking in "cherry boys" and would often service them without large fees (resulting in some GIs faking virginity over and over again). *Cherry girl* was also used. The Japanese word for a male virgin is *dotei* (doe-tay). A virgin girl is a *shojo* (show-joe).
>
> *[Sex and the Japanese: The Sensual Side of Japan](https://books.google.com.pe/books?id=PSXRAgAAQBAJ&printsec=copyright)* (by Boye De Mente)

Comment: Amusing side note - "cherry boy" has been borrowed into Japanese to mean "male virgin" (チェリーボーイ / _cherī bōi_; this despite Japanese already having the unambiguous word 童貞 _dōtei_ meaning "male virgin"), and is probably more widely understood in Japanese than in English.

Comment: I've updated my answer further. I'm aware that the terms I offered are uncommon but I considered this question as a more advanced question. It   is obvious that virgin is gender-neutral and it can be found in many dictionaries. If the answer is "virgin is gender-neutral" then why all the hassle. I thought OP was interested in other slang terms.

Comment: So that's where the phrase *to take someone's cherry* comes from?

Comment: @TRiG: All related terms come from *cherry* meaning a female virgin (from 1920s).

Comment: @TRiG the other way around, it comes from an euphemism for rupturing a woman's hymen.

Answer (score -2):

According to the OP, **in Norwegian, the word "svenn" has at least three different meanings**: an apprentice, a young man who never had intercourse, and an unmarried older man.

"an unmarried man, 30 years or older" **as mentioned by the OP**, can be referred to as **"a celibate"** no matter his sexual status.

> - [**celibate**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=cellibate+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=U25cVr45rKTzB7CuqJAI&gws_rd=ssl) (noun) - a person who 
>     abstains from marriage and sexual relations. (typically, but not always, for a religious reason)

A young man who never experienced sex, as mentioned by Jasper in his answer, is a **"virgin"**.  It's the usual word to refer to a young man and can be used for both males and females, any age group. Some related words are: **chaste**, **immaculate** and **virginal**. These are adjectives and the first two are not exactly synonymous with "virgin" (noun).

Edit - "celibate" and "virgin" **are not synonyms**. A celibate abstains from sexual relations and a virgin never had any.

Comment: -1  Celibate suggests your current lifestyle.  You can be celibate without being a virgin

Comment: You can also be a virgin without choosing to be celibate, as I suspect many teenagers would attest.

Comment: The "and sexual relations"  is implied   It's not, really, part of the definition of celibate.

Comment: Did you see the quite relevant comment from smci regarding "The 40-Year-Old Virgin"? There is no age limit on being a virgin. The difference I see between "celibate" and "virgin" is that the former word generally refers to an intentional choice, while the latter simply refers to a state (of never having had sex).

Comment: With you latest edits, I can see where you're coming from a bit more, but the question is "Is there a male counterpart to being a virgin?", not "Is there an English counterpart to the Norwegian word *svenn*?"

Comment: The correct term is "virginal". The other suggestions of things like "cherry boy" or "cherry prick" may be correct but are using totally the wrong register. "Chaste" is not so good because it implies that you are choosing to abstain for some specific reason. If you are virginal it simply means that you've never had sex. That's it.

Comment: "peppersvenn" and "peppermø" aren't really a 3rd usage, just sub-usage of the 2nd...  Like "maid" (young girl, usually a virgin) and "old-maid" (woman, maybe still a virgin, but at least unmarried) - which is pretty much  is what "peppermø" means.  It's also sort of a Norwegian tradition to give a pepper-shaker as a birthday-gift to someone who's still unmarried at 30, to accent his/her status as a "pepper-mø/svenn"

Comment: "Immaculate" does not mean "never had sex". It means clean, pure, free from fault or error. It can be used in a physical or a moral sense: "I scrubbed the windows until they were immaculately clean" or "Bob is the most upstanding person I know: his character is immaculate". Christians say that Christ was born to a virgin and refer to this as the "immaculate conception", but that's a specific term for a specific event.

Comment: @michaelj RE "celibate" Hmm, I looked in several dictionaries and several gave alternate definitions, like 1. abstaining from sex, 2. abstaining from marriage. But in practice, "celibate" is normally used to describe someone who abstains from both marriage and sex for religious or philosophical reasons. I don't think I've ever heard it used for a man who sleeps with hundreds of women but never marries, or a woman, etc.

Comment: The distinction I was trying to make is that being celibate *implies* abstaining from sex, but abstinence from sex is not part of the definition.  That part is covered under different moral criteria. From a religious perspective, a man who has taken a vow of celibacy, but then fails and has sex, is still celibate, but has committed another transgression.

Comment: @Jay - "Christians say that Christ was born to a virgin and refer to this as the "immaculate conception"" is a frequently-encountered  misunderstanding of "immaculate conception". That actually [refers to the conception of Mary](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07674d.htm), the mother of Jesus. She was conceived and born without original sin. In turn, she conceived Jesus through the Holy Spirit - but that event is NOT the immaculate conception.

Comment: @Brandin: "virginal" is just an adjective derived from "virgin." But "virgin" itself is more commonly used.

Comment: @sumelic Yes it is an adjective, but you can trivially translate the usage. E.g. "M. is a virgin." (Honestly it sounds like the person intends that M. is a girl in this statement). -> "M. is virginal." (Now M. could equally well be a man or a woman).

Comment: @floris True. Clumsy of me. Technically one should say "CATHOLICS believe that Mary was born without original sin." Protestants do not. But further discussion on this gets into theology rather than grammar.

Comment: @Jay we agree...